# jQuery UI tooltip not working in fullscreen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When a div that has elements with tooltips is made into a full-screen element, it is not showing tooltips any more. It might be due to the tooltip not being part of the fullscreen container as jQuery UI is adding it to the body. There seems to be no option in jQuery UI to change the parent of the tooltip. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbjv3yq/2/). Is there a workaround for this use case?

Code in JSFiddle:
HTML:

```
<div class="full-screen-div">
  <div class="tooltip">
    This is for tooltip
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <input class="toggle-full-screen" type="button" value="Toggle Fullscreen"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    $(".full-screen-div").tooltip({
      track: true,
    items: ".tooltip",
    content: "123"
  });

  $(".toggle-full-screen").on("click", function () {
     if (document.fullscreenElement ||
            document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
            document.mozFullScreenElement ||
            document.msFullscreenElement) {
          if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
          }
      } else {
          element = $(".full-screen-div").get(0);
          if (element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
         element.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
          } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
      }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.full-screen-div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3em;
  background: white;
}

.tooltip {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you correctly noted, is that JQueryUI adds the tip element to the body. You can change this by re-attaching the element to your desired container in the *open* event.

You should *only* do it when you are in full-screen mode though. The positioning of the tip seems to calculate relative to the window, so if you apply this all the time you end up with the tips showing up in a position offset from their intended place.

Here's a basic example. This assumes you have a function *isFullscreen()* that detects whether you are currently in full screen mode or not.

```
$(document).tooltip({
    open: function (e, ui) {
        if (isFullScreen()) {
            ui.tooltip.appendTo(".full-screen-div");
        }
    }
});
```

Note: You don't have to explicitly *appendTo* when not in full-screen as the element is reset each time.

See this example, provided by @Kishor - [jsfiddle.net/vhzpnsq9](https://jsfiddle.net/vhzpnsq9)

Comment: Thank you @xtempore. I have implemented it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vhzpnsq9/ . Please add it in your answer, so that other people can benefit from it.